# Boolean Modifier isnt working properly

Tags: modeling

Before I start, Im completely new to blender and im pretty sure the problem is with the model itself rather than the boolean modifier.

Im trying to add internal "walls" to this half circle sphere casing thing as shown in the images below.

[image: top view]

[image: bottom view]

[image: the cut I want to make]

[image: Intersect shows problems with model itself]

As you can see above, even though intersect is not what im trying to do, it reveals that there is probably issues with my model itself.
[image: after applying difference]
Now when I apply difference it shows that its not even fully cutting through the parts I want it to. How can I fix this?? Im completely lost and dont know what to search.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YSgJhDOz_GimsEhdL7ro5OEg2cjWcRez?usp=sharing) is my blend file

Comment: the topology of the object called "t" is pretty bad, you have overlapping faces etc, it won't help to calculate the boolean